# Texas TI-alternatives

Tags: math-software, calculator

I've been using a Texas TI graphing calculator at school and am wondering if there are programs for the PC that function similarly (with similar features) as those calculators. I don't need an emulator (its illegal to use one without owning the calculator anyways) but want a program that actually looks like one of those machines and functions like one.

The program should be free (preferably open source), and I'm looking for suggestions as to what programs I should download.

Comment: You could try wolfram alpha.

Comment: @Anonymous: In addition the the nice suggestion by AG, you can look into downloading and learning a [*Computer Algebra System*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems). They have all sorts of goodies and are very helpful in your journeys and much more powerful than what you will find on a calculator (although there are some nice ones of those too). Regards

Comment: I've looked into CAS systems before but many don't seem to have a good GUI... what do you recommend?

Thx Alex, but I want something that works offline too.

Comment: @Anonymous What ones have you tried? What is a good GUI?

Comment: Simple and easy to use (no command line interface), preferably with Natural Display format for equations.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm now using Microsoft Mathematics (free program) which has a GUI, natural display and the CAS features I need.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Mathematics

Download:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=15702